# Hystrix status is not exposed under /health

Tags: java, spring-boot, hystrix, spring-boot-actuator

According to the [doc](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi__circuit_breaker_hystrix_clients.html) my application should serve hystrix data under /health. Despite open circuit-breaker the only thing i see under that url is

```
{"status":"UP"}
```

I expect to see something like that

```
{
    "hystrix": {
        "openCircuitBreakers": [
            "somedata::somedata"
        ],
        "status": "CIRCUIT_OPEN"
    },
    "status": "UP"
}
```

What did I miss?

My build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.10.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }

}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

group = 'com.somecompany'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


ext {
    springCloudVersion = 'Edgware.SR1'
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-hystrix')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}
```

Application class

```
@EnableCircuitBreaker
@SpringBootApplication
public class HystrixDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HystrixDemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Resource under Hystrix control

```
@RestController
public class SomeResourceController {

    @HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "defaultValue", commandProperties = {@HystrixProperty(name="execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds", value="1500")})
    @RequestMapping(path = "/resource-with-hystrix", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public String someResource(){
        URI uri = URI.create("http://localhost:8080/some-resource");
        RestOperations restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        return restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class);
    }

    private String defaultValue(){
        return "local value in case of something goes wrong";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set Health endpoint as not sensitive(default):

```
endpoints.health.sensitive=false
```

> Depending on how an endpoint is exposed, the sensitive property may be used as a security hint. For example, sensitive endpoints will require a username/password when they are accessed over HTTP (or simply disabled if web security is not enabled).

From the documentation of the health endpoint:

> Shows application health information (when the application is secure, a simple ‘status’ when accessed over an unauthenticated connection or full message details when authenticated).

Comment: Now I see 401 under /health :). There must be something else. Tried management.security.enabled=false as a temporary workaround and now it works but ignores endpoints.health.sensitive property.

Comment: The sensitive property is default to false, and tells that you dont need any authentication to see basic info. In order to see the details, you have to authenticate when the Application is secure.

Answer (score 3):

According to [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html#production-ready-health):

> The information exposed by the health endpoint depends on the `management.endpoint.health.show-details` property <...> The default value is `never`.

So, in order to show hystrix information you need to set `management.endpoint.health.show-details` to either one of:

- when_authorized
- always

like so:

```
management.endpoint.health.show-details = always
```

The answer provided by msfoster no longer works (as of Spring Boot 2.1.x and cloud release train Greenwich.RELEASE):

> Endpoint sensitive flag is no longer customizable as Spring Boot no longer provides a customizable security auto-configuration . Create or adapt your security configuration accordingly